# finding a specific index on a two dimensional array

Tags: c#, multidimensional-array

I am creating a game of tic tac toe and numbered the board 1-x (its a dynamic board and the user gets to choose how many rows and columns). I then ask a user for the number of the tile they wish to choose, yet am not sure how to get the indices of the array (two dimensional) which relate to the tile. Without them I am unable to change the tile from the number to an X or an O

Things I have tried so far 
Row = (move - 1) % size (since row and columns have to be the same)
Col = (move - 1 % size

It doesn't seem to work all the time such as a 23 in a 5x5 column. The indices for it are [4,2] yet when I plug them into my equations I get 5.75

Comment: Can you provide sample code of what you are doing? Also, is it safe to assume that user will request  the number of the tile in the form "number:number" or "number,number"?

Comment: As I pointed out in a comment to my answer, if you store size and move as ints, then results of all divisions in question will also be ints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that first row has numbers, `1, 2, ..., numberOfColumns`, second row has numbers `numberOfColumns + 1, numberOfColumns + 2, ..., 2 * numberOfColumns` and so on, you can do the following:

If user enters number `N` then you can say

```
int row = (N - 1) / numberOfColumns;
int column = (N - 1) % numberOfColumns;
```

(`row` and `column` will be zero-based indices).

Comment: I attempted to do the math behind the equations you gave and it didn't work out. I assumed that a user chose to have a 5x5 board. I would then have numbered the board 1-25 with 1 being [0,0] and 25 being [4x4]. I randomly selected 19 to work through your equations and found that row would equal 3.6

Comment: Since N - 1 and numberOfColumns are both integers, "/" is integer division so row will also be an integer. In your example, row = (19 - 1) / 5 = 18 / 5 = 3. In other words, in C# (and many other languages), 7 / 2 = 3, while 7.0 / 2.0 = 3.5. Try and see for yourself.